# I want use the fetch API method to initial the store's state, but why it do not work?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuex

In my `store.js`, I have a `user_data` state, its initial method is `fetch_user_data`:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user_data: util.fetch_user_data('username')
    ...
  }
```

in the `util.js`:

```
util.fetch_user_data = function(username){
   Lml_http('get', Api_urls.productconfig_common.user_data(username), null, response => {

    return response.data  // there get the data, in the debugger shows it.
  }, error => {

  })
}
```

But when I use the `state`'s `user_data`, it is `undefined`.

---

**EDIT-1**

I want in the `store.js` to use the `fetch_util`'s method for fetching data, and commit to the `state`.

**EDIT-2**

my `lml_http` code are bellow:

```
var lml_http = function (method, url, params, success_cb, error_cb, multipart_formdata=undefined) {

  var format_to_form_data = function(data){

    let formData = new FormData()
    for (let item in data) {
      formData.append(item, data[item])
    }
    return formData
  }

  var lowercase_method = method.toLowerCase()

  var formated_params = params

  var header_config = null

  if (multipart_formdata) {
    header_config = {
      headers: {
        'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
      }
    }

    formated_params = format_to_form_data(formated_params)
  }

  if(lowercase_method === "get") {

    formated_params = {params: formated_params}

    if (!header_config) {

      Axios.get(url, formated_params).then(response => {
        success_cb(response)
        return
      }).catch(response => {
        error_cb(response)
        return
      })
    } else {
      Axios.get(url, format_to_form_data(formated_params), header_config).then(response => {
        success_cb(response)
        return
      }).catch(response => {
        error_cb(response)
        return
      })

    }

    return
  }
  else {


    if(!header_config) {

      Axios[method](url, formated_params).then(response => {
        success_cb(response)
      }).catch(response => {
        error_cb(response)
      })
      return
    }else {
      Axios[method](url, formated_params, header_config).then(response => {
        success_cb(response)
      }).catch( response => {
        error_cb(response)
      })
      return
    }

  }

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just create an action to fetch the user data as follows:

```
export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    user_data: null
  },
  mutations: {
    setUserData(state, data) {
      state.user_data = data;
    }
  },
  actions: {
    fetchUserData({ commit }, username) {
      Lml_http(
        "get",
        Api_urls.productconfig_common.user_data(username),
        null,
        response => {
          commit("setUserData", response.data);
        },
        error => {}
      );
    }
  }
});
```

Then dispatch this action in the `created()` hook of theroot vue instance

```
//main.js

new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserData", "username");
  }
});

`
```

## Edit:

Axios returns a `Promise` by default. So in `lml_http` return Axios calls as below:

```
var lml_http = function(
  method,
  url,
  params,
  success_cb,
  error_cb,
  multipart_formdata = undefined
) {
  var format_to_form_data = function(data) {
    let formData = new FormData();
    for (let item in data) {
      formData.append(item, data[item]);
    }
    return formData;
  };

  var lowercase_method = method.toLowerCase();

  var formated_params = params;

  var header_config = null;

  if (multipart_formdata) {
    header_config = {
      headers: {
        "Content-Type": "multipart/form-data"
      }
    };

    formated_params = format_to_form_data(formated_params);
  }

  if (lowercase_method === "get") {
    formated_params = { params: formated_params };

    if (!header_config) {
      return Axios.get(url, formated_params)
        .then(response => {
          success_cb(response);
        })
        .catch(response => {
          error_cb(response);
        });
    } else {
      return Axios.get(url, format_to_form_data(formated_params), header_config)
        .then(response => {
          success_cb(response);
        })
        .catch(response => {
          error_cb(response);
        });
    }
  } else {
    if (!header_config) {
      return Axios[method](url, formated_params)
        .then(response => {
          success_cb(response);
        })
        .catch(response => {
          error_cb(response);
        });
    } else {
      return Axios[method](url, formated_params, header_config)
        .then(response => {
          success_cb(response);
        })
        .catch(response => {
          error_cb(response);
        });
    }
  }
};
```

Also add a return statement in utils.js

```
util.fetch_user_data = function(username){
   return Lml_http('get', Api_urls.productconfig_common.user_data(username), null, response => {

    return response.data  // there get the data, in the debugger shows it.
  }, error => {

  })
}
```

Now in your action `fetchUserData`

```
fetchUserData({ commit }) {
    util.fetch_user_data('username').then((
      commit("setUserData", response.data);
    });
}
```

In main.js dispatch the action without any payload

//main.js

```
new Vue({
  el: "#app",
  store,
  render: h => h(App),
  created() {
    this.$store.dispatch("fetchUserData", "username");
  }
});
```

Comment: Can I write the `fetchUserData ` in a fetch_util?

Comment: @qg_java_17137 does `Lml_http` return a promise?

Comment: See my EDIT-2, brother.

Comment: @qg_java_17137 that's a bit of refactoring......added my edit to the answer..have a look

Answer (score 0):

Because the fetch api is async, it will return a promise, not the response data. I think you may try something like:

```js
const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
  user_data: null,
  ...
};

util.fetch_user_data('username')
  .then(user => store.user_data = user);

export default store;
```

Comment: @FranklyLau But if I refresh the browser, how can I ensure the `util.fetch_user_data` execute?

Comment: I assume you have a file `main.js` which will import the `store.js` file and bind it to the vue app. The function `util.fetch_user_data` is run at that time, basically everytime you refresh browser, all the javascript will re-run.

Comment: And is there a way for solving the promise issue?

Comment: My code should work and the time sequence would be like this:
1) create a new vuex store (user_data is null)
2) fetch user data
3) create new vue app
4) fetch result come back and set user_data=user
5) vue refresh ui due to store data change

Comment: should I write the `util.fetch_user_data('username')
  .then(user => store.user_data = user);` in the store.js like you? I get error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'then' of undefined`.

Comment: oh, sorry, I miss out your `Lml_http` use callback way. Try this: `util.fetch_user_data = username => new Promise((resolve, reject) => 
    Lml_http('get', Api_urls.productconfig_common.user_data(username), null,
        response => resolve(response.data),
        reject)
);`

Comment: I want the `Lml_http('get', Api_urls.productconfig_common.user_data(username), null, response => resolve(response.data), reject) );` write in other file, is it realizable?